# Flutter plugin: No such module 'google_mobile_ads' in iOS native code

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, flutter-plugin, flutter-ios

I create a Flutter plugin for Admob to reuse in my different projects for banner, interstitial, native ad and rewarded ads. I create it so that I can just add the plugin to other project's pubspec.yaml and use without recode everytime.

It works fine on Android code, the "google_mobile_ads" sdk is recognized and can be accessed without adding any dependency.

But, the problem is that the `google_mobile_ads` is not recognized in my iOS code (to create the Native Ad Factory) when Run Build in Xcode. When I use "Ctrl + Click" the "FLTNativeAdFactory" class to "Jump to Definition" in Xcode, it works but the build fail with the error. See the attached image.

Here is my code and setup:

- admob_ads plugin pubspec.yaml
  [image: admob_ads plugin pubspec.yaml]
- the ios code podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'admob_ads'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.dependency 'Cosmos', '~> 23.0'
  s.platform = :ios, '9.0'

  # Flutter.framework does not contain a i386 slice.
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES', 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386' }
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
end
```

- The ios code tree and error:
  [image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this error log: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/594

Until it gets fixed, this is the current workaround:

In your pubspec.yaml, change

google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.1

to:

```
  google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter
      ref: 356875362ddb2ac2e0056385d2729c093722fb8d
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
```

or this:

```
  google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jjliu15/googleads-mobile-flutter-1.git
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads/
```

I found it worked better when I took the ref: out.

Comment: I have tried your solution. After update the yaml file, I got "Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (9.6.0), ....." when `pod install`. But not work, still got `Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'google_mobile_ads' `

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't posted the indents correctly. Try the above three. I think the new one will work but haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
  google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jjliu15/googleads-mobile-flutter-1.git
      ref: delete_deprecations
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads/
```

Comment: Thank you! I also tried this, but the error is still there :(.